# In the mwmrc file, how can I disable the mouse from resizing or moving a window?

Tags: window-manager

In my local .mwmrc file I have disabled moving and resizing window from the system menu, but I can still use the mouse to move or resize the window.  How do I prevent users from doing that with the mouse?

```
Menu DefaultWindowMenu
{
!   Restore     _R  Alt<Key>F5  f.restore
!   Move        _M  Alt<Key>F7  f.move
!   Size        _S  Alt<Key>F8  f.resize
!   Minimize    _n  Alt<Key>F9  f.minimize
!   Maximize    _x  Alt<Key>F10 f.maximize
!   Lower       _L  Alt<Key>F3  f.lower
!   no-label                f.separator
!   Close       _C  Alt<Key>F4  f.kill
}
```

I'm running SLES 11.  The windows are in a Java Swing application delivered via javaws.  The application developers don't want to manage their windows and expect it to happen at the OS level.

Answer (score 1):

I had to look deeper into the .mwmrc file and mess with the mouse buttons:

```
Buttons DefaultButtonBindings
{
    <Btn1Down>  icon|frame  f.post_wmenu
    <Btn3Down>  icon|frame  f.post_wmenu
    <Btn3Down>  root        f.menu  DefaultRootMenu
}
```